# Transform $3^{n} \mod 7 $ to $ n \mod 7$ form

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I want to go from that form $3^{n} \mod 7 $ to something that doesn't use exponent. 
it says, hint : you should use $ n \mod 7$

I listed the values from $3^0 \mod 7 $ to $ 3^{10} $

$$
3^0  \mod 7 = 1\\
3^1  \mod 7 = 3\\
3^2  \mod 7 = 2\\
3^3  \mod 7 = 6\\
3^4  \mod 7 = 4\\
3^5  \mod 7 = 5\\
3^6  \mod 7 = 1\\
3^7  \mod 7 = 3\\
3^8  \mod 7 = 2\\
3^9  \mod 7 = 6\\
3^{10} \mod 7 = 4\\
$$

Then I want to find a way to get to the values with $n \mod 7$

I tryed with $ 3n \mod 7$ , $3 (n-1) \mod 7$ , 
Also tryed with the gcd(a,n)
also tryed with something like $3(n * n) \mod 7$

Comment: You cannot deduce $3^n\mod 7$ from $n\mod 7$ only. For example, $0\equiv 7\mod 7$, but the values $3^0 \equiv 1$ and $3^7 \equiv 3$ are not identical mod $7$.

Comment: As @azimut says, you want to consider $n\pmod 6$. You can use Lagrange interpolation to find a $5$th degree polynomial to fit these, but I don't see a nice one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Show that the values of $3^n\mod 7$ only depend on the remainder of $n\mod 6$. (Hint: Fermat's little theorem)

Then you can tabulate the values of $3^n \mod 7$ like this: $$\begin{array}{l|llllll}n\mod 6 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\\hline 3^n\mod 7 & 1 & 3 & 2 & 6 & 4 & 5\end{array}$$

Comment: finally figured it out, thanks a lot. $m = n(\mod p-1)$ then $a^m = a^n (\mod p)$